# Query regarding the positive definite ness of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that a matrix A is positive definite. I want to know, if adding any positive term to all the diagonal elements of A still makes it positive definite

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because the sum of two positive definite matrices is positive definite.  (And a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries is positive definite.)